# Stripe - Fatal Error - No API key provided - PHP

Tags: php, api, namespaces, stripe-payments

I've been getting the following error when submitting the charge.php stripe payment page. I'm also not using composer. I'm not sure why this error is happening.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\Authentication' with
>   message 'No API key provided. (HINT: set your API key using
>   "Stripe::setApiKey()". You can generate API keys from the
>   Stripe web interface. See https://stripe.com/api for details, or email
>   support@stripe.com if you have any questions.' in
>   /home/site/html/test/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php:132 Stack trace: #0
>   /home/site/html/test/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php(64):
>   Stripe\ApiRequestor->_requestRaw('post', '/v1/customers', Array,
>   Array) #1 /home/site/html/test/stripe/lib/ApiResource.php(120):
>   Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/customers', Array, Array) #2
>   /home/site/html/test/stripe/lib/ApiResource.php(160):
>   Stripe\ApiResource::_staticRequest('post', '/v1/customers', Array,
>   NULL) #3 /home/site/html/test/stripe/lib/Customer.php(59):
>   Stripe\ApiResource::_create(Array, NULL) #4
>   /home/site/html/test/charge.php(9): Stripe\Customer::create(Array) #5
>   {main} thrown in /home/site/html/test/stripe/lib/ApiRequestor.php on
>   line 132

Here are the files I'm working with:

**config.php**

```
<?php
require_once('stripe/init.php');

$stripe = array(
  "secret_key"      => "foobar" /*  Actual secret key redacted */,
  "publishable_key" => "foobar" /* Actual publishable_key redacted */
);

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

**Form:**

```
<?php require_once('config.php'); ?>

<form action="charge.php" method="post">
  <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable_key']; ?>"
          data-description="Access for a year"
          data-amount="5000"
          data-locale="auto"></script>
</form>
```

**charge.php**

```
<?php
  require_once('config.php');

  $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => 'customer@example.com',
      'source'  => $token
  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'customer' => $customer->id,
      'amount'   => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd'
  ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
?>
```

Also here is that ApiRequestor.php function that seems to be causing an issue:

```
private function _requestRaw($method, $url, $params, $headers)
{
    $myApiKey = $this->_apiKey;
    if (!$myApiKey) {
        $myApiKey = Stripe::$apiKey;
    }

    if (!$myApiKey) {
        $msg = 'No API key provided.  (HINT: set your API key using '
          . '"Stripe::setApiKey(<API-KEY>)".  You can generate API keys from '
          . 'the Stripe web interface.  See https://stripe.com/api for '
          . 'details, or email support@stripe.com if you have any questions.';
        throw new Error\Authentication($msg);
    }

    $absUrl = $this->_apiBase.$url;
    $params = self::_encodeObjects($params);
    $langVersion = phpversion();
    $uname = php_uname();
    $ua = array(
        'bindings_version' => Stripe::VERSION,
        'lang' => 'php',
        'lang_version' => $langVersion,
        'publisher' => 'stripe',
        'uname' => $uname,
    );
    $defaultHeaders = array(
        'X-Stripe-Client-User-Agent' => json_encode($ua),
        'User-Agent' => 'Stripe/v1 PhpBindings/' . Stripe::VERSION,
        'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $myApiKey,
    );
    if (Stripe::$apiVersion) {
        $defaultHeaders['Stripe-Version'] = Stripe::$apiVersion;
    }

    if (Stripe::$accountId) {
        $defaultHeaders['Stripe-Account'] = Stripe::$accountId;
    }

    $hasFile = false;
    $hasCurlFile = class_exists('\CURLFile', false);
    foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
        if (is_resource($v)) {
            $hasFile = true;
            $params[$k] = self::_processResourceParam($v, $hasCurlFile);
        } elseif ($hasCurlFile && $v instanceof \CURLFile) {
            $hasFile = true;
        }
    }

    if ($hasFile) {
        $defaultHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data';
    } else {
        $defaultHeaders['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    }

    $combinedHeaders = array_merge($defaultHeaders, $headers);
    $rawHeaders = array();

    foreach ($combinedHeaders as $header => $value) {
        $rawHeaders[] = $header . ': ' . $value;
    }

    list($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders) = $this->httpClient()->request(
        $method,
        $absUrl,
        $rawHeaders,
        $params,
        $hasFile
    );
    return array($rbody, $rcode, $rheaders, $myApiKey);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composer or manual installation should not have an effect here, it seems for some reason your key is not being properly set! I'd recommend doing a bit of testing.

1. When you view source on your Form is the publishable key being set there?
2. If you include `config.php` in a php file and then do `echo $stripe['secret_key'];` Does it display a key as you expect?
3. Try manually adding `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);` in your `charge.php` --- does the request work? If that doesn't work try adding `\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxyyyyyzzz");`, does that work?